# How to pass data from fragment to ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat, pass-data

I have PatientList class that extends fragment and other AddPatient class that extends ActionBarActivity. Now i want to pass static string from PatientList to AddPatient then its getting null.Where is the problem?? Why it is getting null???

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I'm understanding but you can add a method in `AddPatient` and within `PatientList` call `((AddPatient) getActivity()).yourmethod(string)`

in `AddPatient`:

```
public receiveString(String mystring)
{
    // do whatever with mystring
}
```

in `PatientList` where needed e.g. onClick or something

```
((AddPatient) getActivity()).receiveString("hello")
```

if you want to pass data to an Activity you are starting with startActivity() instead you should do something like (if you are inside a fragment)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddPatient.class);
intent.putExtra("param_string", mystring)
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

in `AddPatient`

```
private String mMyString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    mMyString = getIntent().getStringExtra("param_string");
}
```

you can add Integer, Strings and Serializable stuff, multiple times

Comment: you can call that code in `PatientList` effectively passing a string in `AddPatient`, what's the problem?

Comment: I've added the code to pass a string from a fragment of an activity to *another* activity

Comment: it's exactly the same code I use in my app and always worked, make sure you are not doing something differently

Answer (score 0):

Instead of some dark magic proposed by @sherpya you should check how it is done by google at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

You should create an interface that is for that instead of creating dependency upon concrete Activity. What if you decide later to reuse this fragment in another Activity ?
In same cases you can use some event bus http://square.github.io/otto/